# Files not found after uploading to appfog

Tags: appfog

I used isotope for my thumbnail images.
Everything works fine in my development server.

After I have updated my files in appfog using "af update".
The above page spits out this error in inspect element.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) http://neudev.hp.af.cm/static/plugin/css/isotope.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) http://neudev.hp.af.cm/static/plugin/js/isotope.init.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) http://neudev.hp.af.cm/static/plugin/js/isotope.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) http://neudev.hp.af.cm/portfolio/undefined?1367668124923
```

I try to check it inside appfog directory and i found out the files mentioned above do exists

```
advitor@ubuntu:~/workstation/neudev$ af files neudev app/neudev/staticfiles/plugin/js --all
====> [0: app/neudev/staticfiles/plugin/js] <====

camera.js                                66.7K
camera.min.js                            38.4K
isotope.init.js                           808B
isotope.js                               15.7K
jquery.easing.1.3.js                      7.9K
jquery.min.js                            91.7K
jquery.mobile.customized.min.js          17.1K
```

here is my template for the portfolio page

```
{% extends 'base.djhtml' %}
{% load humanize %}
{% block title %} | {{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}defaults/css/pages/portfolio.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}plugin/css/isotope.css" />
{% endblock %}
{% block maincontent %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="shelf">
            <div class="shelfContainer">
                <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                    <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
                    <ul id="filters" class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-filter="*">All</a>
                            </li>
                        {% for c in cat %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-filter=".{{ c.id }}">{{ c.title }}</a>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    <div id="isotope-container" class="tab-content">
                        {% for p in folio %}
                            <div class="well well-small pull-left {{ p.category.id }}" style="margin-left: 20px">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img width="180px" src="{{ p.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ p.title }}" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{  STATIC_URL }}plugin/js/isotope.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{  STATIC_URL }}plugin/js/isotope.init.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't know what is wrong here, i hope someone could help me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know now where i did wrong, I forgot to run collectstatic